# Why Iterable.sum() is slow in Kotlin?

Tags: performance, kotlin, benchmarking

I've noticed surprising difference between performance of `Itarable.sum()` and direct for loop with manual sum. Consider this:

```
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var sink = 0;
    repeat(5) {
        println(measureTimeMillis {
            var sum = 0
            for (i in 1..10_000_000) {
                sum += i
            }
            sink += sum
        })
    }
    repeat(5) {
        println(measureTimeMillis {
            sink += (1..10_000_000).sum()
        })
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, using `Iterable.sum()` is up to 10 times slower,
compared to the code that is almost identical to [sum() implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/bea94d1d5945c57e2999531b0ed5df6653133805/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L2344).
Why is that?

**Update:**

When I target js, then sum() is only slightly slower.

`measureTimeMillis()` can be defined as:

```
import kotlin.js.Date
public inline fun measureTimeMillis(block: () -> Unit): Double {
    val start = Date.now()
    block()
    return Date.now() - start
}
```

**Update2:**

On same linux machine, jvm sum() is even slower than js. Here are results for 100_000_000 iterations for jvm (Oracle jdk9) and js (latest chrome):

```
105   // jvm raw loop
76    // jvm raw loop (jit?)
75    // jvm raw loop (jit?)
75    // jvm raw loop (jit?)
70    // jvm raw loop (jit?)
633   // jvm sum()
431   // jvm sum()
562   // jvm sum()
327   // jvm sum() (jit?)
332   // jvm sum() (jit?)

110   // js raw loop
108   // js raw loop
232   // js raw loop
227   // js raw loop
227   // js raw loop
321   // js sum()
284   // js sum()
264   // js sum()
266   // js sum()
265   // js sum()
```

So, on same machine, jvm seems to be slower than js when using `sum()`. Yet another surprise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly, we're comparing super-optimized tight loops here. I'm seeing quite stable results across repetitions for the "manual sum" and wild variance in the "built-in" case. This indicates GC activity.

Upon launching VisualVM and using its VisualGC plugin, I confirmed that there's no GC activity during the manual sum computation, but a lot of it in the built-in case.

Looking at the generated bytecode, the difference becomes apparent: the idiom `for (i in 1..range) { ... }` compiles directly into a counted loop. This is actually [documented](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html):

> Integral type ranges (`IntRange`, `LongRange`, `CharRange`) have an extra feature: they can be iterated over. The compiler takes care of converting this analogously to Java's indexed for-loop, without extra overhead.

Unfortunately, the same optimization doesn't apply to the extension function `Iterable.sum()` because it must work for any `Iterable`. The compiler *could* see what's going on and introduce another intrinsic, which would simply convert the whole thing into the resulting sum without computation, or use a direct formula if the range bounds aren't hardcoded.

JavaScript is on a similar footing here because it, too, has a powerful JIT compiler. I can't comment anything specific, but it most probably avoids allocation in the hot loop.

Comment: Thanks Marko. Intergral ranges in fact makes a difference. When I change my loop to `for (i in (1..100_000_000).asIterable()` it's almost as slow as `sum()`. Any idea why higher GC activity in `sum()` vs. loop?

Comment: `Iterable.sum()` treats the range as `Iterable<Integer>` and thus allocates one object per iteration. The counted loop is just `for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) sum += i;`